# Show full text outside group object fabricjs

Tags: javascript, textbox, fabricjs

I am trying to merge textbox and group in fabricjs
when I set text, It doesn't show full text.
how to set full text?
[image]

```js
var iText4 = new fabric.Textbox('Text noasasasasasasasasasabcdefghxyz', {
  left: 50,
  top: 100,
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  width: 30,
  styles: {
    0: {
      0: { textBackgroundColor: 'blue', fill: 'green' },
      1: { textBackgroundColor: '#faa' },
      2: { textBackgroundColor: 'lightblue' },
    }
  }
});

var group = new fabric.Group([ iText4 ], {
  left: 150,
  top: 100,
  width: 60,
});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.add(group);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width='500' height='400'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The group's width is smaller than the text's width, causing it to be cut off. Removing it should solve your problem.

```
var group = new fabric.Group([ iText4 ], {
  left: 150,
  top: 100
});
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/p6c2trg8/1/